# BSOD repair boot sector ERROR 0xc000000d

Tags: windows-10, boot, bsod

I've recently started getting this error on my laptop (the suggestion from dell has been to reinstall windows and not fix the underlying problem)

[image: Bluescreen of Death Boot]

I've tried using "Start up repair" but that fails.

[image: Start up repair]

Then I've tried using bootrec commands but they also fail, with access denied error.

[image: bootrec commands]

I’ve also tried maybe making an image of the hard drive but the software redo backup also cannot locate the partition for windows

[image]

[image]

Boot screen

[image]

Diagnostic results

[image]

Comment: When you ran the /rebuildbcd command it didn’t identify any Windows installation so it basically did nothing, this error, is connected to your EFI partition.  I had this problem last year, spend 5 months trying to solve it, never was successfully

Comment: It’s odd I’m using redo backup to try make an image of the hard drive but the source hdd that contains windows is not appearing in the hdd list .. could it be that the hdd containing windows has failed? Hence no installs and access denied

Comment: But the SSD does appear on boot screen I’m so confused I’m running memory diagnostics on the laptop to rule out other hardware components

Comment: The error you received is “device not found”

Comment: I’ve updated question and with some more information

Comment: The HDD that’s not showing up, GPT or MBR?

Comment: @Ramhound I have no idea most of the commands in the command line return process is using this file or access denied

Comment: @Ramhound diskpart works but even that command is not detecting the SSD